# How to Inject JQuery Manually in Laravel Dusk

Tags: jquery, laravel, requirejs, laravel-dusk

I am using the require-js to organize my JS files and since I've used the jquery with define modules, the Laravel Dusk tests cannot recognize the jquery and it returns the following error message:

```
unknown error: $ is not a function
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

In my app.js file I've used jquery like this:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($)
{
   // js codes...
});
```

Now, how can I inject jquery manually to Laravel Dusk?

(( I am using Laravel 5.4 ))

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/315

Comment: Yes, but all of my js codes are inside define() module and so the Dusk can't load it by requirejs. How can I introduce requirejs to the Dusk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations, you can use the requirejs version for executing jquery scripts in Dusk pages.

For example, hiding an element:

```
public function someScript(Browser $browser, $selector)
{
    $selector = $browser->resolver->format($selector);

    $browser->script("requirejs(['jquery'], function($) { $(document).find(\"$selector\").hide(); });");
}
```